# Does a HTTP resource that accepts range requests always specify content-length?

Tags: http, http-headers, http-content-length, http-range

Before starting a `Range` request, I first check if it is supported using a HEAD request. Normally I get back something like this:

```
curl -X HEAD -i http://bits.wikimedia.org/images/wikimedia-button.png

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
Content-Length: 2426
Accept-Ranges: bytes
...
```

Is the `Content-Length` guaranteed per the HTTP/1.1 specification in this case? I can't find a definitive answer but it seems like I would need to know the `Content-Length` before I do a `Range` request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

As per any other response with a 200 status code, such a response **SHOULD** (in the RFC 2119 sense of "**SHOULD**" which can be summarised as "better have a damn good reason why not, and be able to say what that damn good reason is") include a length (RFC 2616 §14.13) bar a few scenarios in which it is prohibited (§4.4) (in particular, the value must be *both* the entity and transfer length and as such is only valid when the transfer-encoding is "identity" [the default]). There is no reason why an `Accept-Ranges` header need not be sent along with a chunked and/or compressed transfer-encoding. (Different to compressed content-encoding, in which case `range`, like `content-length` refers to the compressed size).

Some things worth noting:

1. A server may always ignore a `range` request and respond with the full length, even if it had suggested otherwise. (§14.35.2) Hence, you should always be prepared to receive this.
2. A server may honour a `Range` or `If-Range` even if it didn't indicate it would through `Accept-Ranges`. (§14.5)
3. A valid `Range` could be e.g. `123-` meaning "send me everything from octet 123 on to the end. (§14.35.1)
4. A `Range` of e.g. `123-500` is valid even if the size of the entity is less than 500, in which case as many octets as are available are to be sent. However, it would not be valid if there were fewer than 123 octets in the entire entity. (§14.35.1)
5. Values other than `bytes` are valid but undefined for `Accept-Range`. (§3.12) This means that the server is doing something non-standard, so unless `bytes` is also mentioned, you should interpret it as not including an `Accept-Range`.
6. While not including `Content-Length` in a response including `Accept-Range` is valid, it's not very likely. As a rule, if you were to treat such responses as if they had not included an `Accept-Range` header then you would be safe from mis-steps in the face of such behaviour, while also benefiting from the range behaviour the vast majority of the time it came up.

Comment: It is your Point 4 specifically which lead me to believe that I *require* the Content-Length before making a Range request. How else can I know that the initial range `123-` is less than the resource length?

Comment: You can't, though if you don't already have 123 bytes, and you aren't doing some sort of distributed download (which would ideally want the length for its own reasons) why would you want to? If you do already have 123 bytes then it must have at least 123 bytes.

Comment: Also, if you did try to get too far-off a range, a 416 response would let you know that's what happened.